# StringRedisTemplate thread safety capability

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot, redis

I use StringRedisTemplate to add entries to redis as below.

```
public void processSubmission(final String key, final Map<String, String> submissionDTO) {
    final String hashKey = String.valueOf(Hashing.MURMUR_HASH.hash(key));
    this.stringRedisTemplate.expire(key, 60, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    final HashOperations<String, String, String> ops = this.stringRedisTemplate.opsForHash();
    Map<String, String> data = findByKey(key);
    String json;
    if (data != null) {
        data.putAll(submissionDTO);
        json = convertSubmission(data);
    } else {
        json = convertSubmission(submissionDTO);
    }
    ops.put(key, hashKey, json);
}
```

Since this operation can be do in multiple threads, there can be situation of race condition leads to data lost.

The documentation said about RedisTemplate "Once configured, this class is thread-safe."

Do I have to add thread safety capability explicitly? I dont see any synchronize key word in StringRedisTemplate or RedisTemplate source.

Answer (score 1):

Being thread-safe doesn't mean there's a `synchronized` keyword somewhere. You can write thread-safe code without `synchronized`, and you can easily write thread-unsafe code even when using `synchronized`.

`RedisTemplate` is thread-safe, as documented. So you just need to make sure that `processSubmission` is thread-safe.

Comment: I would like to know how RedisTemplate  achieve thread safe? Could you pls explain. Secondly, I can make processSubmission synchronize, but then again I think it would be a bottle neck when many threads invoke it and cause a performance issue

Comment: I'm not going to start explaining how `RedisTemplate` is thread-safe. I don't even know how they've achieved it, but since they've documented it to be thread-safe, I'm assuming they aren't lying. If all you understand about thread-safety is the `synchronized` keyword, then you need to do some studying. Maybe start with https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/ if you don't have any other resources at hand.